# Should you create a custom eventWrapper component for react-big-calendar?

Tags: reactjs, calendar, react-big-calendar

There is no documentation for adding a `eventWrapper` and I've seen a few comments saying it's not meant to be overwritten. Should we be using this or trying to create custom `eventWrapper` component to override this exsisting one?

For me I don't want the `.rbc-event-label` also want to dynamically in JS change the styling. Or should I be just changing things in the CSS?

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically apply additional classes and styling to your events by using the `eventPropGetter` property. This property takes a function that should return an object of class names and styles to be applied to an event (automatically added to the eventWrapper).

```
const eventRenderProps = (event, start, end, isSelected) => {
  let result = {};
  // Code to conditionally add 'className' or 'style' to the result
  return result; // {className?: String, style?: Object}
}

//
<MyCalendar eventPropGetter={eventRenderProps} />
```

It's important to note that this method is called on every displayed event, and will get called again on each as an event is selected or changed/updated. Also important to note that `className` is to be a **String**, and not an object, so if you require several classes you will need a space delimited list of class names.